# Get lambda parameter type

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, c++11, type-traits

I would like some way to get the first parameter type of a lambda function, is this possible?

e.g.

instead of:

```
template<typename T>
struct base
{
     virtual bool operator()(T) = 0;
}

template<typename F, typename T>
struct filter : public base<T>
{
     virtual bool operator()(T) override {return /*...*/ }
};

template<typename T, typename F>
filter<T> make_filter(F func)
{
      return filter<F, T>(std::move(func));
}

auto f = make_filter<int>([](int n){return n % 2 == 0;});
```

I would like:

```
template<typename F>
struct filter : public base<typename param1<F>::type>
{
     bool operator()(typename param1<F>::type){return /*...*/ }
};

template<typename F>
filter<F> make_filter(F func)
{
      return filter<F>(std::move(func));
}

auto f = make_filter([](int n){return n % 2 == 0;});
```

Based on Xeo's answer this is what I got working in VS2010:

```
template<typename FPtr>
struct arg1_traits_impl;

template<typename R, typename C, typename A1>
struct arg1_traits_impl<R (C::*)(A1)>{typedef A1 arg1_type;};

template<typename R, typename C, typename A1>
struct arg1_traits_impl<R (C::*)(A1) const>{typedef A1 arg1_type;};

template<typename T>
typename arg1_traits_impl<T>::arg1_type arg1_type_helper(T);

template<typename F>
struct filter : public base<typename std::decay<decltype(detail::arg1_type_helper(&F::operator()))>::type>
{
    bool operator()(typename std::decay<decltype(detail::arg1_type_helper(&F::operator()))>::type){return /*...*/ }
};

template<typename T, typename F>
filter<F> make_filter(F func)
{
      return filter<F>(std::move(func));
}
```

I've tried simplifying the the code, but any attempt seems to break it.

Comment: I was looking at some trick with `std::fuction::first_argument_type`, however VS2010 doesn't seem to implemenet `first_argument_type`.

Comment: Complicated. *Very* complicated, especially without variadic templates and with VS2010. You'll need some kind of function-traits that splits the actual type of a function pointer down to its components and use `function_traits<decltype(&F::operator())>::param1_type` or the like. VS2010 has problems with that code though, let me see if I can find my question about it...

Comment: You can't use `std::function<F>` for that, as `F` is the lambda type and not a signature like `bool(int)`.

Comment: I'm curious: Why does filter need to know the arguments to the function? Can't you just write a generic perfect forwarding function with variadic arguments?

Comment: Because filter has a method e.g. `operator()(T)` which needs to know the argument type.

Comment: @ronag: It would be the easiest if you just made that a template too and simply forward.

Comment: @ronag: `template<class Arg> bool operator()(Arg&& arg){ _f(std::forward<Arg>(arg)); }` where `_f` is the stored function.

Comment: Updated question to make more sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *easiest* option would be to just make the `operator()` a template itself:

```
template<typename F>
struct filter
{
     template<class Arg>
     void operator(Arg&& arg){
       // use std::forward<Arg>(arg) to call the stored function
     }
};

template<typename F>
filter<F> make_filter(F func)
{
      return filter<F>(std::move(func));
}

auto f = make_filter([](int n){return n % 2 == 0;});
```

---

Now, *theoretically*, the following code should *just work*. However, it doesn't with MSVC10 thanks to a bug:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
 
template<class FPtr>
struct function_traits;
 
template<class T, class C>
struct function_traits<T (C::*)>
{
    typedef T type;
};
 
template<class F>
void bar(F f){
  typedef typename function_traits<
      decltype(&F::operator())>::type signature;
  std::cout << typeid(signature).name();
}
 
int main(){
    bar([](int n){ return n % 2 == 0; });
}
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/FPkxW)'s an example on how it would look with GCC. MSVC10, however, simply doesn't compile the code. See [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264031/why-does-the-compiler-try-to-instantiate-a-template-that-i-dont-actually-instan) for further detail. Basically, MSVC10 doesn't treat `decltype(&F::operator())` as a dependent type. Here's a work-around that was devised in a [chat discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2266358#2266358):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <type_traits>

template<class FPtr>
struct function_traits;

template<class R, class C, class A1>
struct function_traits<R (C::*)(A1)>
{   // non-const specialization
    typedef A1 arg_type;
    typedef R result_type;
    typedef R type(A1);
};

template<class R, class C, class A1>
struct function_traits<R (C::*)(A1) const>
{   // const specialization
    typedef A1 arg_type;
    typedef R result_type;
    typedef R type(A1);
};

template<class T>
typename function_traits<T>::type* bar_helper(T);

template<class F>
void bar(F f){
  typedef decltype(bar_helper(&F::operator())) fptr;
  typedef typename std::remove_pointer<fptr>::type signature;
  std::cout << typeid(signature).name();
}

int main(){
    bar([](int n){ return n % 2 == 0; });
}
```

Comment: Great! However, what about if filter::operator() is virtual?

Comment: @ronag: Then you got a problem. :| Why would it need to be `virtual` if the class itself is templated on the function / functor type anyways?

Comment: Because this is a simplified example, and in my real code filter has a base class.

Comment: @ronag: Let me edit in a sec to show you a possible solution.

Comment: @ronag: Came to the conclusion that you're basically screwed with MSVC10. :|

Comment: @ronag: FWIW, I finally came around to actually submitting [a bug report to Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/716358/decltype-of-a-member-of-a-template-parameter-not-considered-a-dependant-name#details).

Comment: Does the generated lambdax classes have any hidden typedefs one might be able to use?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6352/discussion-between-ronag-and-xeo)

Comment: @ronag: `typename function_traits<U>::type` would be a function type (`bool(int)` in this case). Functions can't return other functions, so because the substitution would create an illegal type, the function gets SFINAE'd out instead.

Comment: Updated my question with my implementation of your solution.

Comment: @ronag: You could atleast typedef the parameter type inside the derived class. :P And factor that `base<...>` thing out into a simple `get_base<F>` template that hides away the nastiness.

Comment: @ronag: Why do you ask? I already told you in the chat that you can't return a function type from a function.

Comment: Nvm, I missed the ::type part.